# In the Admin Dashboard, can I choose which sections to display?

Tags: menus, wp-admin, dashboard

For the editor I would just like to display Pages, Posts, Media and Menus. Is there a way of doing this with the functions file or similar?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to remove the menu options, you can use the remove_menu_page function in your functions.php file

[remove_menu_page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page)

Add this code to functions.php:

```
    function remove_menus(){
       remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );                  //Dashboard
       remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );          //Comments
       remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );                 //Appearance
       remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );                //Plugins
       remove_menu_page( 'users.php' );                  //Users
       remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );                  //Tools
       remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );        //Settings
   }

   add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```

That should remove everything except the options you want to keep.

If you want to remove the menu options for editors only, use an if statement within the function:

```
function remove_menus(){
    if(current_user_can('editor')){
        remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );                  //Dashboard
        remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );          //Comments
        remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );                 //Appearance
        remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );                //Plugins
        remove_menu_page( 'users.php' );                  //Users
        remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );                  //Tools
        remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );        //Settings
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```

Comment: Can this be done on a per user basis? For just the Editors for example?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to remove the menu options for only certain user roles by using an if statement within the remove_menus function. See updated answer.

Comment: What about the other way around, what if Pages, Posts, Media and Menus are the only ones I want to display? Can I do it that way?

Comment: Do you want to remove those menu options? The code above is to remove menu options, so that a user logged in as an editor should only see the menu options: Pages, Posts, Media and Menus. The other menu options listed in the code will be removed.

Comment: That's great, the only thing is that the 'nav-menus.php' page is what I was hoping to have on the sidebar as well! That was why I queried adding specific menu items instead of removing them! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to manage the contents of the admin menu?  If so, perhaps this plugin would help: [Admin Menu Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/)